# C# XmlSerializer Problems with serializer.Serialize

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization, xmlserializer

Long story short, I am making an ATM application for a school assignment.  Bank account information needs to be stored into a file to keep those account balances up to date.

I have two questions - (1) In the serialization process I get an error on line 49 that says:

(field)Account[] RunAccount.acctArray

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'RunAccount.acctArray'

(2) Do my read-in and read-out serialization locations make sense?

I am very new at this and feel like I have no idea what I am doing so all advice is appreciated and welcome.  Thanks!

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    namespace Bank_Midterm_Project
    {
        public class RunAccount
         {
    Account[] acctArray = new Account[3];
    private static int i;
    bool acctscreated = false;
    bool acctsloaded = false;
    private object test;

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        RunAccount ra = new RunAccount();
        int input;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a choice:");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Populate Accounts");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Load Accounts From File");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Select Account");
            Console.WriteLine("4) Exit");

            input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (input == 1 && ra.acctscreated == false)
            {
                ra.populateArray();
            }
            else if (input == 2 && ra.acctsloaded == false)
            {
                ra.readArray();
            }
            else if (input == 3 && ra.acctscreated == true)
            {
                ra.pickAccountMenu();
            }
            else if (input == 4)
            {
              Stream FileStream = File.Create("test.xml");
              XmlSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(typeof(Account[]));
              serializer.Serialize(FileStream, acctArray);
              FileStream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                if (input == 1 && ra.acctscreated == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have already populated the accounts.  Please try again.");
                }
                else if (input == 2 && ra.acctscreated == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have already loaded the accounts.  Please try again.");
                }
                else if (input == 3 && ra.acctscreated == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You must create the accounts first.  Please try again.");
                }
            }


        } while (input != 5);
            //ATM atm = new ATM();
            //atm.topMenu();



    //ra.writeArray();
    //{

    //}
}

    //private void readArray()
    //{
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void readArray()
    {
        Stream FileStream = File.OpenRead("test.xml");
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Account[]));
        acctArray = (Account[])deserializer.Deserialize(FileStream);
        FileStream.Close();
    }
//}


    public void populateArray()
    {
        //int[] acctArray = new int[3];
        //prompt for username
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter three account numbers, separated by spaces:");
        string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        for (int i = 0; i < acctArray.Length; i++)
        {
            acctArray[i] = new Account(tokens[i]);
        }
        acctscreated = true;
    }

    public void pickAccountMenu()
    {
        string sinput = null;
        int input = -1;
        while (input != 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 0, 1, or 2 for your account.  4 to quit.");
            sinput = Console.ReadLine();
            input = Convert.ToInt32(sinput);
            if (input != -99)
            {
                acctArray[input].menu();
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class XMLSerializer : XmlSerializer
{
    public XMLSerializer(Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: declare `Account[] acctArray = new Account[3];` inside the `public static void Main(String[] args)`

Comment: or use `ra.acctArray`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ra.acctArray`. You have to access that property using the class instance variable.